# Передача данных между приложениями C# (.net core)

Tags: linux, .net-core

Необходимо передавать данные быстро между двумя приложениями (.net core).
Необходимо кроссплатформенное решение предполагается запуск под linux.
(Понятно что общая память, это очень хорошо и удобно, но проблема что в linux нет memory named) - Возможно я не совсем компетентен в этом вопросе.

Что можете посоветовать ?

Comment: В linux нет чего? Почитайте для начала [shm_overview - overview of POSIX shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) и [sem_overview - overview of POSIX semaphores](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) (хотя во многих случаях тривиальных [fifo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) вполне достаточно)

Comment: "Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Named maps are not supported."

Named maps - это функция, предоставляемая Windows. Как правило, отображаемые в память файлы работают путем межпроцессного взаимодействия, отображая один и тот же файл в несколько процессов.

Разве не так ?

Comment: https://github.com/AdaptiveConsulting/Aeron.NET/issues/72

Comment: Т.е. из среды C# нет нормального доступа к syscalls? (может тогда не стоит ей пользоваться в *nix?)

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста , а чем можно заменить (mmf) что бы не сильно в скорости потерять ?

Comment: Наверное я не совсем понял, поэтому хочу уточнить -- стандартный [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) не работает в реализации среды C# в Linux?

Comment: @avp, C# основан на winAPI, там нет точных аналогов 1-в-1 POSIX-вызовов... так что туда лучше не лезть со своими заморочками... вот [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/94e9d02ad70b2224d012ac4a66eaa1f913ae4f29/src/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles/src/System/IO/MemoryMappedFiles/MemoryMappedFile.Unix.cs#L24) описано, почему они не сделали именованные отображения в стиле `shm_open`. На мой взгляд, основная причина, которая забила последний гвоздь в крышку гроба идеи сделать это — невозможность надёжно удалить файл созданный `shm_open` со смертью последнего открывшего его процесса.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, прочел, спасибо! Но я все равно не понимаю, что именно мешает использовать POSIX с семантикой именно  POSIX, а не win-аналогов. Понятно, что это будет уже не portable, а чисто \*nix-вое решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут многое завивист от того, что это за приложения.

Если это какие-то REST сервисы, то они вполне могут обращаться к API друг друга. В общем случае можно попробовать построить шину данных на основе какого-нибудь RabbitMQ, Nats или Kafka.